# Xamarin Mac Enable sandboxing

Tags: macos, xamarin

I have used FFMPEG for Xamarin Mac project to compress the video.

But I am facing the issue as below.

ERROR ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list: [( "com.amit.CVLive.pkg/Payload/CvLive.app/Contents/MacOS/CvLive", "com.amit.CVLive.pkg/Payload/CvLive.app/Contents/Resources/FFMPE3/ffmpeg", "com.amit.CVLive.pkg/Payload/CvLive.app/Contents/Resources/ffmpeg" )] Refer to App Sandbox page at https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/ for more information on sandboxing your app."

I tried the below also.

Point 1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/app-fundamentals/sandboxing#sandboxing-quick-start

Point 2.[image]

Comment: App Sandbox is the top level bundle, but all nested bundle executables have to code signed also, you can use `codesign` to sign (`--sign`) them as an additional build step and also verify (`--verify`) the resulting app bundle to determine if everything is signed properly before submitting it to the App Store.

Comment: How to create Code sign for the nested bundle executables have to code signed also. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue,
On the "Mac Signing" option make sure:

- Choose a custom etitlements file
- Enable the option "Sign the installer packer"

before archiving the App for publishing

[image]